# where to store my android app database?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm new to android. I have Login and register option and sqlite database.
I want to know if i have to store the database on server in order to login my app, or it's save automatically on google's server?

Comment: Rule of thumb, never store any credentials.

Comment: @SiKni8 What logic do you base that on?? User335. What is wrong with storing the Sqlite database on your android?

Comment: @Doomsknight I forgot to add -- unless you are using some sort of cryptography and not as plain text.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really built an app like that, but I've researched a little. I hope it helps you too.

You can use the SQLite database to store stuff locally, although I prefer using SharedPreferences because of its easy implementation for smaller details like username and some general preferences.

However, to create a client server login-registration like app, you can use GCM (google cloud messaging) and a server. Now its hard to explain what exactly am I trying to say and how to implement it, but thanks to this guy who made a Tut outta it. I tried building it and it works like a charm. I used a local DB like Xamp, but it works.

Link: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Link 2: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html

These tuts will help you get a gist of GCM and how to configure a server to communicate with GCM and your mobile devices. Good luck!

Comment: besides the login database i have another database that store text that i want to share between users, can i use the same way you offered to do that?

Comment: Yes, you can use that or as i said.. If its not too much of data... You can use shared preferences.. Or a local sql database and the same GCM to pass on the strings or strings id. Example:
Your local db stores strings as Id : string in the database... Then u can pass srring id and retrieve the equivalent string value.... Just one of many ways to achieve what you want.